# Using LibreOffice Impress' Presenter's Console with a single display

Tags: libreoffice

Sometimes, you do not need to drive the slides when giving a presentation, (someone else is doing it for you on another screen, or you e-mailed the slides to a remote site), but it would still be nice for the presenter to have a consistent view and access to speaker notes.

How can a user force Libreoffice to the presenter's screen when a single display is present? X wizardry aside, there ought to be a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a macro on the Libreoffice community site that lets one manually toggle presenter mode without a second screen.

[Add show presenter view in Impress | ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/64534/feature-request-add-show-presenter-view-in-impress/)

Not the cleanest solution, but better than launching a second x-server.